# tar file number limitation

Tags: linux, gzip, tar

Does gzip has file limitation
Thanks
ER

Comment: Streaming algorithms generally don't have a filesize limit.

Comment: Please don't edit your question asking something completely different after you already accepted an answer to another question. Start a new question instead.

Comment: Ok, will do it next time thanks.

Comment: I will edit it again with the first question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gzip` only takes one file. If you need to compress more, create an archive with `tar` (or another archiving tool) and `gzip` it (usually resulting in a *.tar.gz* or *.tgz* file).

*EDIT*

ALso, there is no 4 GB limit on gzip any more for almost a decade.

Comment: On what exactly? I doubt you will hit any file number limitations.

Comment: thanks I ran to issue with tar and gzip failed,I tought it might related to number of files limitation .

Comment: Why don't you ask about your actual problem with what actually happened instead of asking about theories?

Comment: Thank you mark, I ran to issue with tar and gzip and I was thinking it is related to some kind of limitation . thank you all for your answers .